# Axios with Mutual TLS: how to provide credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, axios

In a browser, I can load Axios from a CDN with a script tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

However, the class **https.Agent**, used for mutual TLS, is not present and it is not clear how to load it.  My code is roughly:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false, 
  cert: ...,
  key: ...
})
....
axios.post('https://....', {...}, { httpsAgent } )
```

Error in Console:  *Uncaught ReferenceError: https is not defined*

Local examples often show require (below), but https should be loadable from a CDN like unpkg?

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require("axios");
```

(PS: its useless to google for 'https')

Comment: Do you have a public SSL cert on this? In case if its giving you any certificate error

Comment: try to instanciate a new axios instance like `const customAxios = axios.create({ httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })})` and then do your network-request with that instance

Comment: Thanks but the error is loading the class https.Agent, not with the self-signed certs or network connection..

Comment: `fs` is from node. you can't do that in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using client browser certificates.  When the web server has SSL client verification enabled, it will request the clients certificate.  With this technique, the cert is passed out of band and not with the Axios post() call.

On Nginx, this can be configured with **ssl_verify_client** and **ssl_trusted_certificate** which determines the CA(s) used to verify the certificate.  During the initial TLS exchange, a popup in the users browser will prompt them to select the certificate to send.

Users must configure a client .p12 (combined cert and key) in your browser. On Chrome:

Chrome Preferences > Privacy and Security (Additional  Settings) > Manage Certificates

HTTPS request can then be made without explicit auth:

```
    axios.post('https:....., dataArg)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to change the browser settings?